# Angular with lazy loading has bundle without output hash

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, micro-frontend, angular-module-federation

We have an **Angular 16** application with **micro frontends** and using **lazy loaded modules**. 
For each Micro Frontend, all built bundles have a hash appended, except one file (the one having the same name of the mfe). Below "Activity" is one of our mfe:

[image: mfe bunldes]

This js file gets downloaded when the remote mfe (here Activity) gets loaded. 
However, since it does not have an output hash as the other bundles, isn't there the risk that the browser agent uses the cached version of it? 
Checking the network tab I can see there is a `apps_activity_src_app_app_module_ts.xxx.js` file downloaded (referring to the lazy module) and also `activity.js` (referring to what?).

The index.html file does not reference the `activity.js` file, only `main.xxx.js`.

Comment: Hashing is configured in angular.json, isn't there some exclusion of that file?

Comment: There is a property, "outputHashing" that defines the cache-busting strategy. We use the value "all", therefore all built files (media and not should have an output hash) I am not sure to which part of the code that bundle without hash refers.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, the file without hash refers to the remote entry file (we are using module federation); therefore, it is clear now why it was not getting any output hash on the build.

We will exclude these files from the NGINX cache rules as we did for the index.html file.